# Access 2013 customized ribbon does not work

Tags: ms-access, vba, ribbon, ms-access-2013

Below is the my UI, table, record and error message when I click "Pres Me"

[image]
[image]

My XML is:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="dbCustomTab" label ="My menue">
       <group id="MyGroup" label="Button Demo">
        <button id="menue" label="Press me" onAction="OpenMenue" />
       </group>
      </tab>
   </tabs>
  </ribbon>
 <backstage>
  <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
 </backstage>
</customUI>
```

My code is attached which is in module1.

```
Option Compare Database

'declaration
Public objRibbon As IRibbonUI

Public Sub OnRibbonLoad(objRib As IRibbonUI)

Set objRibbon = objRib

End Sub

'our callback for the SampleButton
Public Sub OpenMenue(ctl As IRibbonControl)

If (ctl.ID = "menue") Then

MsgBox ("You have just executed the OnButtonPress callback when    clicking" _
& vbCrLf & "the Ribbon SampleButton!")

End If
```

End Sub

The code and XML is from http://burningpenguin.com/viewtopic.php?t=176.  I change

```
button id="menue" label="Press me" onAction="OnPress"
```

to

```
button id="menue" label="Press me" onAction="OpenMenue"
```

Becuase the OnAction name is different in the XML and module.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What you have so far should work. Are you sure you created a standard code module (not a class module) for your code? I would delete your code module, and then create a new one (choose module, not class module when you create this code module), Then cut + paste your code back end. after you save your code, while in the VBA editor, do a debug->compile to ensure the code compiles.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it is in code module. By your suggestion, I complie code and error messager shows up. With the error message, I find the issue. Microsoft office 15.0 object library is was not checked. I checked Microsoft Access 15.0 object library. Thank you again. Finally, it works perfectlly.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain to me, how this work, i try, but don't work for me.

Comment: XML is ribbon design code while it needs VBA to do others.  Not sure what you need.  Please provide detail and I can try to help.

Comment: Try adding `()` to the end of the action in the XML. Like this: `onAction="OpenMenue()"`

Answer (score 0):

The OnPress keyword is an event associated with the button. There is no event called OnMenue so your change doesn't make sense. If you want to call the method in the code something else you will have to rename your button, it is currently called menue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am new for Ribbon.  This is my first trial.  I can undersatnd what you say,  But, I do not know how to change my code.  Let we keep the button ID as "menue".  How should I have OnAction on the the XML and how should I have my method in the code?  Where should I have the method?  It is in module1 now. Thank you again for your help.